# FOSRESTBUNDLE returning 500 on android calls

Tags: android, symfony, fosrestbundle

## android

```
String url = "******";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.d("DATA", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

## symfony code

```
/**
     * Get ServiceProvider.
     *
     * @param ServiceProvider $venue
     *
     * @return ServiceProvider
     *
     * @Route\Get("/venue/{id}", options={"expose"=true})
     *
     * @ParamConverter("venue", class="CoreBundle:ServiceProvider")
     *
     * @View(serializerGroups={"all"})
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     * resource=true,
     *     description="Getting Venue information",
     *     output="CoreBundle\ServiceProvider",
     *     statusCodes={
     *         200="Returned when successful",
     *         403="Returned when the Venue is not authorized to get Venue",
     *         404={
     *             "Returned when the user is not found",
     *             "Returned when something else is not found"
     *         }
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function getVenue(ServiceProvider $venue)
    {
        return $this->get('service_provider_model')->getBy('id',$venue->getId());
    }
```

when i hit in the browser the statusCode is 200 and its working
same on postman and from iOS i can read the json, but not from any android emulator or device.
i always get 500 status code so i cant read the data.
StringRequest or JSONRequest all not working.
btw i tried to change the symfony code to

```
return new Response("hi");
```

and then i can read the response.

## logcat

```
E/Volley: [323] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for 
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: get more information on your symfony log on that error. tailf app/logs/[env].log

Comment: i went through it all that wasn't the problem i am using URLConnection now will explain in an answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `StringRequest` and `JSONRequest` still looking into them. Now i am using the [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) where i also faced the same problem but after changing the headers and adding the correct request header it worked.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
```

complete code for reference

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by yamennassif on 21/02/2017.
 */

public class GetURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static JSONObject VenueData;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String urlString = params[0];
            URL url = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder;
            try
            {
                url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
                connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
                connection.connect();

                // read the output from the server
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe)
                    {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("AsyncTasks","MainActivity.GetUrl.doInBackground()"+e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```